# Log who and what is being searched for?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to log an action on a PHP search.

I have 3 simple pages:

1. login for authenticate my user
2. the search function
3. the page to display my search form and the result

I would like to know who searched what (for example user "Bob" searched at 11:22 for "John"'s email address)

I have enabled MySQL logs that do not allow me to get this type of information.
Can I do this in PHP?

Here is the search function:

```
<?php
//DB Connect
define('DB_HOST', 'xxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'xxxx');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME,
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false ]
  );
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  die($ex->getMessage());
}

Echo "Hi ".$_SESSION['username'];

// SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE ? OR `user_mail` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%", "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
  echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

and the result page

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<?php

/* [SEARCH FOR USERS] */
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  require "search.php";
}

/* [DISPLAY HTML] */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
    <form method="post">
      <h1>
        Search user email from username
      </h1>
      <h1>

      </h1>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- [SEARCH RESULTS] -->
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      if (count($results) > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $r) {
         printf("<br> Username : %s <br> eMail :  %s</div>", $r['user_name'], $r['user_mail']);
        }
      } else {
        echo "No results found";
      }
    }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The login page is not really interesting.

Comment: You could use [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) with `$message_type=3` which will log messages to a user-specified file

Comment: Yes.You can do it with PHP. You can create a table with columns say - username, search_time and search_info. Then as the search button is submitted, insert the corresponding values into the table before displaying the search result. You can now create another page where the who search what will be displayed

Comment: This is totally possible and the [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) project makes this sort of stuff very easy.  I would advise against using a database table for log related information. Its ok in the short term without a huge number of users, but it will quickly become a bottleneck.  RDBMS' are for organizing data and the relationships between them.  It is not very well suited for indefinite text logging.  Some type of NoSQL solution will be a much better choice, elastic search comes to mind.  If you do end up using the RDBMS, make sure the text datatype is not loaded in memory.

Comment: Thanks to all, I don't really know PHP. So I guess for me the easy way is to follow the hans-könig recommendation ; create a table to store theses informations.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is something that would be possible in any language. You just need to store the searches in a DB table.

At its simplest, create a table with 3 columns - `user_name`, `search_term`, `search_time`.

Add this code before or after your `//SEARCH` section.

```
//STORE SEARCH
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `Searches_Table` (user_name, search_term, search_time) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['username'], $_POST['search']]);
```

You can of course add some additional error checking. I also suggest using the `user_id` but I didn't see one in your code. If you're not already, store the `user_id` in `$_SESSION` and `INSERT` that instead. That way if the `user_name` ever changes you can still link it to the user easily.